# How to cp all files within /var/log without using sudo

Tags: linux, shell, root, cp

This is in shell script. I want to create a directory copy of /var/log while preserving directory structure (so not `tar`).

I do this by making a directory and using `cp -R /var/log cpdir` However, some files in the /var/log needs root permission and when I do `sudo cp -R /var/log cpdir` it asks for a password and I want my shell script to run smoothly without any input.

I can't run the whole script as root, though. I only want `cp` to run as root to be able to copy the whole /var/log.

I saw
`sudo su <<HERE ls /root HERE`
and the commands run inside the HERE block will be run as root. However, it looks so blocky.

Is there any way to do this in one line?

Comment: Why can't you use `sudo` or even do it under root?

Comment: If I use `sudo` it prompts for a password, and I don't know if I'm allowed. If I do it under root, then the copied directory is created under root, so if my instructor checks the copied directory structure using only `tree`, it shows 0 subdirectories and 0 files. Only by using `sudo tree` can the structure be seen.  I can't rely on a note or something to my instructor saying please use sudo when checking my output.

Comment: You should speak to your instructor.  If they've told you to do something that requires root privileges (such as copying /var/log) then you need to confirm with them that using `sudo` or `su` or `super` or similar is OK.   BTW, why do you think that tar doesn't preserve the directory structure?  it does.

Comment: also, are you supposed to do this on YOUR machine or theirs?  if yours, you can write a wrapper script to just do the copy (and nothing else. with hard-coded source and target directories) and configure /etc/sudoers to allow your user to run that script as root without entering a password - see `man sudoers`.

Comment: I will ask my instructor for permission to use root privileges. But it is holiday where I am until monday and the deadline for this is tuesday, so I need a backup plan just in case. As for the `tar`, we were told that he will check using `tree`, and if I run `tree cpdir.tar` or `tree cpdir.tar.gz`, it says 0 files and 0 directories? So I'm actually not sure about using `tar`.

Comment: I will check `sudoers`, thanks!